# Using generic extension method to map entity to view model

Tags: c#, automapper

I'm trying to create a generic extension method that works on any class and map its data to another class supplied.

What I'm trying to achieve is as follows

I have a class User, and another class UserVM

```
User dbUser = new User();
UserVM userMapped = dbUser.MapToViewlModel<UserVM>();
```

And from the inner implementation of the method I'll use AutoMapper Mapper.Map()

Here's my code

```
public static class DataMapperExtensions
    {
        public static M MapToViewModel<M>(this T input)
            where T : class
            where M: class
        {
            return Mapper.Map<T, M>(input);
        }
    }
```

the T never compiles, I even tried the code below:

```
public static class DataMapperExtensions<T> where T: class
    {
        public static M MapToViewModel<M>(this T input)
            where M: class
        {
            return Mapper.Map<T, M>(input);
        }
    }
```

DataMapperExtensions get underlined saying "Extension Method must be defined a non-generic static class".

Is what i'm asking for even possible?
Please let me know and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use

```
public static M MapToViewModel<T,M>(this T input)
```

Comment: and the usage will be like
UserVM mappedUser = dbUser.MapToViewModel<User, UserVM>(); ?